# Refresh DataSource after SaveChange does not work

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, savechanges

I add data in an `ObjectSet` and did `SaveChanges` on `ObjectContext`. But the new data does not shown in the `DataGrid`!

**Code:**


`bsWork.DataSource = Program.EC.Addresses;
...
Address newAdr = new Address();
//change properties newAdr
...
Program.EC.Addresses.AddObject(newAdr);
Program.EC.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);`
How to refresh data or view new data?

#### UPD: Solution

`...
bsWork.Add(newAdr);
Program.EC.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);
...`

Comment: My solution:
`bsWork.Add(newAdr);
Program.EC.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);`
and it works =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this code may helpful for you.

`try {
    // Try to save changes, which may cause a conflict.
    int num = context.SaveChanges();
    Console.WriteLine("No conflicts. " + num.ToString() + " updates saved.");
}
catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException) {
    // Resolve the concurrency conflict by refreshing the 
    // object context before re-saving changes. 
    context.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, orders);`

```
// Save changes.
context.SaveChanges();
Console.WriteLine("OptimisticConcurrencyException "
    + "handled and changes saved");
```

}

Comment: i know this code! I found solution: `codebsWork.Add(newAdr);`